# Powershell to remove particular text from a file

Tags: xml, powershell

Im not really sure how best to approach this.
I want to replace text in xml.rels files.

They contain xml data but dont seem to like being opened with $xml=New-Object XML

I want to remove all path information in the Target tag.

A file example is ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/externalLinkPath" Target="/Finance/Audit/Mgt%20Accts%202020/MGT%20ACCTS%20-%20Copy2/Mgt%20Accts%20MAR%2020.xlsx" TargetMode="External"/></Relationships>
```

So in thie case I wish the file to become...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/externalLinkPath" Target="Mgt%20Accts%20MAR%2020.xlsx" TargetMode="External"/></Relationships>
```

Now the Target could contain any path so I would need to find the last "/" in Target and just keep the text after that.

Thanks for any help at all.
P

Comment: Please add the code you tried so far.

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Path "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy3\Mgt Accts APR 20 unzipped\xl\externalLinks\_rels\" | 
Foreach-Object {
    #$content = Get-Content $_.FullName

    write-host $_.FullName

     $xml=New-Object XML

    $xml.Load($_.FullName)

    $nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("/Relationships");
    foreach($node in $nodes) {
        write-host $node.GetAttribute("Target")
    }
}

Comment: Hi @Alex_P I can't get it to say whats in the Target Attribute with my code, let alone change it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by loading the XML file(s), loop through the  elements and then change the Target attribute using the `SetAttribute()` method:

```
$sourceFolder = "Y:\Finance\Audit\Mgt Accts 2020\MGT ACCTS - Copy3\Mgt Accts APR 20 unzipped\xl\externalLinks_rels"

# PowerShell versions below 3.0 need to use:
# Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter '*.xml' | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } | Foreach-Object {

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter '*.xml' -File | Foreach-Object {
    # load the xml file
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw

    # loop through the <RelationShip> elements and change the Target attribute
    foreach ($relationNode in $xml.Relationships.Relationship) {
        # or use $newTarget = Split-Path -Path $relationNode.Target -Leaf
        $newTarget = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($relationNode.Target)
        $relationNode.SetAttribute("Target", $newTarget)
    }
    $xml.Save($_.FullName)
}
```

Comment: @pwhelan You are filtering on `-Filter '*.xml.rels'`.. Are your xml files renamed like that really?. Now, `Get-ChildItem` cannot find anything, hence the error. Also, are you sure the path in `$relsFolder` is correct? (pointing to a FOLDER, not a FILE). P.S. What version of PowerShell are you using? Versions below 3.0 do not have the `-File` switch so for these you need to use `| Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object { ..`